# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing variable name where it shouldn't be

Tags: jquery, passwords, registration

here's my code:

```
    $("#js_password_2").onkeyup(function() {
```

and this line, according to the browser console turns out to be the place of the error somewhy... But there's no variable in the line, nor in my goals to be it here.

The goal of this script is to check whether entered passwords match before the registration.
Many thanks who answers

Comment: Please provide the error message you are receiving

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask] pages.   In this case, also read [mcve] - we need enough code to *reproduce* the error - as it stands that's not the case.  It's likely in the comparison code rather than the keyup code.

Comment: Note that `$("#js_password_2").onkeyup` *will* give you an error, but it's `$("...").onkeyup is not a function`.  If that's your error, please be precise as this is very different form "*missing variable name*" (and is also not a `Syntax Error`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here(the very first line of the script):

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#js_password_2", function({
```

Instead, I had to write function() with 2 brackets at the end

And after fixing this, yes, as freedom-m said, .onkeyup() is not a function, but this was not the question, it were further.

Comment: That's not how it was in your question...